# Right shift operator

Tags: operator-keyword, bit-shift

I spent several hours today hunting for a bug until I found
something I don't understand.

This is the code I've been working with:

```
unsigned long k,l,m;
k = 1000;
l = 33;
m = k>>l;
```

It gives `m=500` i.e. it apparently shifts by `l mod 32`!

I have logically expected 0.

Is this something I have just overlooked and never noticed?

Comment: What architecture are you running on? x86 can only shift 31 binary places.

Comment: Try casting l as __int8 or __int16 and see if you get similar results

Answer (score 1):

In C, I believe it is not specified what will happen if you use shifts that are too large for the size of the value that you are shifting, so having the shift count wrap is perfectly acceptable (and is what x86 and IIRC PowerPC do).  In Java, the wrapping behavior you saw is mandatory.

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI C standard says:

> If the value of the right operand is
>   negative or  is  greater  than  or
>   equal to the width of the promoted
>   left operand, the behavior is
>   undefined.

So, shifting by 33 isn't the same as 33 times shifting by one ...

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility you are confusing 1(one) and l(letter L) as this has happened to me before !! (double check perhaps by changing x=33; m = k>>x ?)